# How do I enable User 1 rights in minimal installation?

Tags: 8, users, installation-profiles

I have Drupal 8 minimal installation profile and it does not seem to have provided *super user* status to the first admin account created during the installation process.

How do I enable it?

Comment: Welcome to drupal.stackexchange,  what is your Drupal version? do you looked at  users tables on your database? is there any user there?

Comment: Thank you. Drupal 8 (minimal install). Yes, there are two entries (uid,uuid,langcode): `0,c87da1b7-26f7-415c-88cb-ed625697cd24,en` `1,622c8cd9-ab33-4953-9904-1b6fceb1dc6d,en`. But `user__roles` table is empty

Comment: what are you missing ?

Comment: @rémy you tell me.

Comment: If I were you, I would use normal/regular installation. Minimal installation is just a big headache. You're better off using normal/regular and then uninstall the modules you do not want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User 1 doesn't need any roles to have super user status. User 1 is exempted from the permissions system entirely. So, they automatically have all permissions, regardless of roles they may or may not have.

Comment: Yes. Think of user 1 as 'root' in linux. But also, do not delete user 0, or user 1.